# Tomcat register resource

Tags: java, tomcat, resources

is it possible to register any file under some directory (in tomcat) to access it (by url) from a java program?

something like:

```
 pseudo-code
 registerResource("file.txt","http:\\localhost:8080\file.txt);
 [...]
 File txt= new File( getResource( "http:\\localhost:8080\file.txt" ) );
```

Can u make some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in the root folder of an war. And then deploy this war in your Tomcat.